# How do I 'Lock Selection' like Photoshops in Xcode StoryBoard

Tags: xcode, swift, locking, photoshop

When I edit `ImageView`, `UIButton`, or other objects on the StoryBoard Canvas,
it is very hard to select the layer behind them. I want to lock selection for top layer like **Photoshop**, or in **3DMax** what is known as *Freeze Selection*.

[*Freeze Selection*](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/3DSMax/files/GUID-B6650710-B62B-4BAD-8178-81A12DFB2432-htm.html) explanation:

> You can freeze any selection of objects in your scene. By default,
>   frozen objects, whether wireframe or rendered, turn a dark gray. They
>   remain visible, but can’t be selected, and therefore can’t be directly
>   transformed or modified. Freezing lets you protect objects from
>   accidental editing and speeds up redraws.

Comment: can you describe what you are trying to achieve with "locking" . Not everyone here knows photoshop or 3DMax

Comment: for example here is 'A'object and 'B'object, 'B'object are behind from 'A'object. so it is hard to select 'B'object. so can not edit in this situation.  in photoshop and 3dmax can be Apply 'Frozen selection' or 'Lock Layer'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the best you can currently do is switch the upper view to NOT `Installed` at which point the offending view will completely vanish until you switch it back on again

[image]

The disadvantage is that its really easy to leave it uninstalled and drop a bug into your app. The only indication of this situation is normally a warning in your project file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much i found yours. but little bit uncomfortable warning things.. any way.. very good ^3^

Answer (score 2):

Press `Shift` + `Right Mouse Button` to select. It will show you all the objects currently under your mouse cursor, in an ordered list.

Note: This doesn't lock anything, but it will make selection easier for you.

**Update**: In the *Identity Inspector*, there is a *Lock* property. If you set this to **All properties**, then even if you move the object, it will revert back to its locked position. However it does not lock selection on this object, nor does it make you unable to select it.

Comment: wow good function.. `shift`+`Right Mouse Button` good but is there not Lock action? like Photoshop layer Lock function?